# Branching statements doesn't work? Giving me a negative answer when it's supposed to be positive

Tags: c++

This is a class assignment that I can't seem to figure out. The assignment tells us to prompt a user for 2 numbers, those numbers each represent the radius of 2 separate circles. We are then  supposed to find the difference between the areas of these circles by subtracting the smaller area from the larger. 
I have been fine up to that part, sometimes it works other times it doesn't, but I have been testing it with the numbers 3 and 4, which gives me the areas of 9.42477 and 12.56632 respectively. But the difference keeps coming out as -3.14... and none of the answers are supposed to be negative if you're subtracting the smaller number from the larger number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double areaOfCircle(double radius) 
{
  return radius * 3.14159;
}

int main()
{
double Num1;
double Num2; 

printf("Type in a number: ");
scanf("%lf", &Num1);
printf("Type in a second number: ");
scanf("%lf", &Num2);

double areaOfCircle1 = areaOfCircle(Num1);
double areaOfCircle2 = areaOfCircle(Num2);
double areadifference = 0;
// this is where youre supposed to subtract 
// the area of the smaller circle form the area of the
//larger circle, but I keep getting a negative number
// when using the numbers 3 (Num1) and 4 (Num 2)
// should a;ways be a postive number or 0. 

    if (areaOfCircle1 < areaOfCircle2)
{
  areadifference = areaOfCircle2 - areaOfCircle1;
}
    else (areaOfCircle1 > areaOfCircle2)
  {
    areadifference = areaOfCircle1 - areaOfCircle2;
  }

 printf("The difference between the areas is: %lf\n", areadifference);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code with a debugger? EDIT: if I fix the compilation error (`else` -> `else if`), [cannot reproduce](https://ideone.com/rqPsoc). Did you save/recompile your source file, before running the compiled executable?

Comment: You can't give a condition to `else`.

Comment: `else (areaOfCircle1 > areaOfCircle2)` should be `else if (areaOfCircle1 > areaOfCircle2)`

Comment: does not compile, after else is "error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token"

Comment: To everyone that helped, THANK YOU. I got the code right in the end and i edited it with some of your comments and it worked. I was using the wrong file and kept compiling the old file that didnt work instead of the functioning edited one. Stupid mistake but all comments helped me polish it so thank you regardless!

Answer (score 0):

Your area calculation is wrong, area of circle is pi*r^2, but you have pi*r. And if you had checked what your area values came out as you would have seen that.

Comment: Careful with that XOR operator.

Comment: I wasn't asking about the calculation, but i appreicate the imput even though it doesn't help resolve my issue reagardless. The equation given for the area was one our professor told us to use.